# Why is my Server appears to only able works whenever my `BufWriter` and `BufReader` are in a separate function?

Tags: rust, tcp, io, buffer

I have this simple code that handles the request over a stream.

```rust
fn handle_request(stream: TcpStream){

    // Create a buffer reader
    let mut buf_reader = BufReader::new(&stream);

    // Create a buffer to store the data
    let mut buffer = Vec::<u8>::new();

    // Read the data into the buffer
    buf_reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buffer).unwrap(); // can be replaced by `read_line()`

    // Convert the buffer to a string
    let str_buffer = String::from_utf8(buffer.clone()).unwrap();

    // Handle the request
    respond_to_client(&str_buffer, &stream); // Assume that this writes "VALUE\n" to the stream
}
```

and I have this code in my `test.rs` to test this functionality:

**Code 00**

```rust
fn main(){
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:9073").unwrap(); // server address

    let mut my_buf_writer = BufWriter::new(&stream);

    my_buf_writer.write(b"GET|1|ALL\n").unwrap();

    let mut my_buf_reader = BufReader::new(&stream);

    let mut buffer = String::new();

    println!("Reading line");
    my_buf_reader.read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap(); // Doesn't stop

    println!("{}", buffer);

}
```

However, for some reason, this don't work at all UNLESS, I separate my `writer` and `reader` in a separte function like this:

**Code 01**

```rust
fn main(){
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:9073").unwrap(); // server address
    write_in_database(&stream);
    read_from_database(&stream)
}

fn write_in_database(stream: &TcpStream){

    let mut my_buf_writer = BufWriter::new(stream);

    my_buf_writer.write(b"GET|1|ALL\n").unwrap();
}

fn read_from_database(stream: &TcpStream){

    let mut my_buf_reader = BufReader::new(stream);

    let mut buffer = String::new();

    println!("Reading line");
    my_buf_reader.read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap(); // Now for some reason, it stops.

    println!("{}", buffer);
}
```

I don't really get what's the difference between the two. **Code 00** doesn't stop reading the stream even though the returning value has `\n` UNLESS I restructure my code into **Code 01** then it would work. Can someone give me an explanation?

Comment: Probably something about the `BufWriter` getting dropped, does `drop(my_buf_writer);` before you start to read help as well?
f

Comment: @cafce25 I just tested it, and you are correct about it, Thanks. However, can you give me an explanation as to why `BufWriter` needs to be dropped in order for the `BufReader` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the data doesn't get written to the `TcpStream` until you `flush` it, that happens automatically when the `BufWriter` is dropped. Unless you do so the the server is waiting for the client to start talking, and the client is waiting for the server to respond to the unsent message in other words you're in a deadlock.

In addition to the two solutions already in your post and the comments simply ensuring that the data has ben sent with a `flush` also works:

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter, Write, BufRead};
fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:9073").unwrap();
    let mut my_buf_writer = BufWriter::new(&stream);

    writeln!(my_buf_writer, "GET|1|ALL").unwrap();
    my_buf_writer.flush().unwrap();

    let mut my_buf_reader = BufReader::new(&stream);

    let mut buffer = String::new();

    println!("Reading line");
    my_buf_reader.read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap(); // Doesn't stop

    println!("{}", buffer);
}
```

Tip: a plain `nc -l 9073` as "server" helps debug such problems, here you see the "Reading line" message on the server console before it sent any data.